# Trouble with installing additional modules on Postgresql 9.1 on ALT-Linux

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-extensions, linux

I'm trying to create extension under postgresql 9.1 (Linux):

```
CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm;
```

but got error:

```
ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/share/pgsql/extension/pg_trgm.control": No such file or directory
```

This file **exists** and has r/w permissions for all users:

```
[root@postgresql extension]# pwd
/usr/share/pgsql/extension
[root@postgresql extension]# ls -l | grep pg_trgm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  4977 Apr  6  2013 pg_trgm--1.0.sql
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  4230 Apr  6  2013 pg_trgm--unpackaged--1.0.sql
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   177 Apr  6  2013 pg_trgm.control
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: When you copy `pg_trgm--1.0.sql` to `pg_trgm.sql`, does the error go away?

Comment: @dezso I've tried it - same result.

Comment: If you `su` as `postgres`, do you still see the files?

Comment: @dezso sorry? I don't understand

Comment: As root, type `su postgres`, give the password and check if you can `ls  /usr/share/pgsql/extension/*trgm*` - just for excluding that some of the parent directories is missing the necessary permissions.

Comment: Are you sure, you installed the appropriate contrib package? [More details.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12100638/error-when-creating-unaccent-extension-on-postgresql/12101055#12101055)

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter yes, I'm sure. As it was clarified later, it is known bug of ALT linux: https://bugzilla.altlinux.org/show_bug.cgi?id=27878

Answer (score 1):

In this particular situation what did help me:

It was needed just to copy `extension` directory from `/usr/share/pgsql/extension/` to `/var/lib/pgsql-root/usr/lib/pgsql/extension/`.

That's all folks.

Comment: No config changes involved?

Comment: @dezso there aren't any config changes

Comment: BTW, I have not got yet needed reputation for creation new `tags`, but this question relates to specific linux version - `ALT Linux`. It seems, that this solution relates only to it.

Comment: That makes very little sense. Is the PostgreSQL server perhaps running within a `chroot`?